# Problema al actualizar datos desde Sql tiempo real con SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

Estoy utilizando signalr para la actualizacion de registros en tiempo real y mostrarlos en una tabla para el lado del cliente con conexion a sql, establezco la conexion, cuando ejecuto la aplicacion cargan todos los datos pero cuando actualizo la BD no se muestra la actualizacion en la tabla del lado del cliente, pero cuando le doy F5(refrescar) en el navegador recien se visualizan los datos actuales. No encuentro el error tampoco visualizo ningun error en consola. adjunto el codigo para sugerencias :) gracias

Cliente:

```
<body>
<h1>Hola</h1>

<div class="table table-responsive">
    <table id="tbl-productos" class="table table-bordered table-striped"></table>
</div>

<script src="~/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/aspnet/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.min.js"></script>


<script>

    $(function () {
        fnCrearTabla();
    });


    function fnCrearTabla() {

        var tabla = $("#tbl-productos");
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/listadoProductos",
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {

                if (data.length > 0) {

                    //tabla.empty();

                    var thead = "<tr>";
                    thead += "<th>id</th>"
                    thead += "<th>nombre</th>"
                    thead += "<th>precio</th>"
                    thead += "<th>Stock</th>"
                    thead += "</tr>"

                    tabla.append(thead);

                    var array = [];
                    var tbody = "";

                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        tbody += "<tr>";
                        tbody += "<td>" + data[i].id + "</td>"
                        tbody += "<td>" + data[i].nombre + "</td>"
                        tbody += "<td>" + data[i].precio + "</td>"
                        tbody += "<td>" + data[i].stock + "</td>"
                        tbody += "</tr>"
                    }

                    array.push(tbody);
                    tabla.append(array.join(""));
                }
            },
            error: function (e) {
                console.error(e);
            }
        });

    }

    var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("http://localhost:63257/tablaHub").build();
    //connection.serverTimeoutInMilliseconds = 100000; // 100 second}

    connection.on("ActualizarGrilla", function () {
        fnCrearTabla();
    });

    connection.start().catch(function () {
         console.error(e);
    });

</script>
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IProductoServicio _productoServicio;
    public HomeController(IProductoServicio productoServicio)
    {
        this._productoServicio = productoServicio;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public JsonResult listadoProductos()
    {
        var data = _productoServicio.Listado().ToList();
        return Json(data);
    }
}
```

Starup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _webHostEnvironment;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
    {
        this._webHostEnvironment = webHostEnvironment;

        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(_webHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        _configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton(_configuration);

        #region IOC

        services.AddScoped<IProductoRepositorio, ProductoRepositorio>();
        services.AddScoped<IProductoServicio, ProductoServicio>();

        #endregion

        services.AddSignalR();


        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);

    }


    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapHub<TablaHub>("/tablaHub");
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

    }
}
```

Y aqui es donde sucede todo mi clase implementada ---> ProdcutoRepositorio.cs:

```
public class ProductoRepositorio : IProductoRepositorio
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly IHubContext<TablaHub> _tablaHub;

    public ProductoRepositorio(IConfiguration configuration,
            IHubContext<TablaHub> tablaHub)
    {
        this._configuration = configuration;
        this._tablaHub = tablaHub;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Producto> Get()
    {
        List<Producto> listProducto = null;
        Producto oProducto = null;
        SqlDependency dependency = null;

        var connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("dbconnection");

        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                cn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("upsGetProductos", cn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                #region SqlDependecy

                cmd.Notification = null;
                dependency = new SqlDependency(cmd);
                dependency.OnChange += DetectarCambios;
                SqlDependency.Start(connectionString);

                #endregion

                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    listProducto = new List<Producto>();

                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        oProducto = new Producto()
                        {
                            Id = dr.IsDBNull(dr.GetOrdinal("Id")) ? -1 : dr.GetInt32(dr.GetOrdinal("Id")),
                            Nombre = dr.IsDBNull(dr.GetOrdinal("Nombre")) ? "nodata" : dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("Nombre")),
                            Precio = dr.IsDBNull(dr.GetOrdinal("Precio")) ? Convert.ToDecimal(0) : dr.GetDecimal(dr.GetOrdinal("Precio")),
                            Stock = dr.IsDBNull(dr.GetOrdinal("Stock")) ? -1 : dr.GetInt32(dr.GetOrdinal("Stock"))
                        };
                        listProducto.Add(oProducto);
                    }
                }
                return listProducto;
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }

        }
    }

    public void DetectarCambios(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
        {
            _tablaHub.Clients.All.SendAsync("ActualizarGrilla");
        }
        Get();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

}
```

y la clase hub...TablaHub:

```
public class TablaHub : Hub
{

}
```

Comment: En la clase Startup contifuration agregar  app.MapSignalR();    el registro de signalR, en tu script de cliente verifica que la coneccion se lleve a cabo  $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            alert("connection started")

Comment: inicalmente utilizaba app.UseSignalR(Hub => Hub.MapHub<TablaHub>(/tablaHub")) pero como ya esta obsoleta reemplace con app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>(Hub => Hub.MapHub<TablaHub>(/tablaHub")) y si existe conexion